# How to use EntityManager as service?

Tags: symfony-2.1

I've checked out version 2.1. Haven't done much. Now trying to use the entity manager in a service:

```
<service id="user.manager" class="%user_manager.class%">
    <argument type="service" id="doctrine.orm.entity_manager" />
</service>
```

But I get the error:

```
Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager::__construct()
must be an instance of Doctrine\DBAL\Connection, instance of Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager 
    given, called in C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\po\vendor\
    doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager.php on line 689 and defined in 
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\po\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager.php on line 129
```

Default config:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   %database_driver%
        host:     %database_host%
        port:     %database_port%
        dbname:   %database_name%
        user:     %database_user%
        password: %database_password%
        charset:  UTF8

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
        auto_mapping: true
```

I've done this many times and I'm unsure what I'm missing now :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sigh, the awesome

```
app/console doctrine:generate:entities
```

didn't generate my repository. I made it by hand and accidentally made it extend EntityManager instead of EntityRepository.